# How to define a "Collection of String" property in UserControl using WinForms in VB.NET?

Tags: string, vb.net, winforms, collections, user-controls

I try to add a collection of `String` to a `UserControl` that I defined in `VB.Net` using `Winforms`.

The code of collection's property is following

```
Private oItems As New StringCollection 'StringCollection 'New List(Of String)

<Category("GridBox")>
'<DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)>
Public Property Items() _
    As StringCollection

    Get
        Return oItems
    End Get

    Set(items As StringCollection)
        oItems = items
    End Set
End Property
```

I use old `Collection` type because I have read that new generic object are not accepted in `Winforms` UserControl.

I defined `StringCollection` type in another source file.

```
<Serializable()>
Public Class StringCollection
    Inherits BaseCollection

    'Private Shadows List As New List(Of String)

    Public ReadOnly Property Item(index As Integer) As String
        Get
            Return List(index)
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Function Contains(sItem As String) As Boolean
        Return List.Contains(sItem)
    End Function

    Public Function Add(sItem As String) As Integer
        Return List.Add(sItem)
    End Function

    Public Sub Remove(sItem As String)
        List.Remove(sItem)
    End Sub

    Public Sub Insert(index As Integer, sItem As String)
        List.Insert(index, sItem)
    End Sub

    Public Function IndexOf(sItem As String) As Integer
        Return List.IndexOf(sItem)
    End Function

End Class
```

All this code compiles without errors.

When I click on `Items` property in `Property` panel in Visual Studio, a window is displayed very quickly and disappears immediately.

What is happening ?

How can I define a String's collection in UserControl ?

Comment: There is already a [`StringCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.stringcollection?view=net-8.0) class in .NET, so there's no reason to define your own. Whether you use that or `List(Of String)`, the property should be `ReadOnly`, e.g. `Public ReadOnly Property Items As New List(Of String)`. That one line is all you need. You should pretty much never be able to set a collection property, which would allow you to replace the entire collection, rather than adding or removing items in the existing collection.

Comment: I tried what you wrote and now dialog box is displayed :-) But when I click on ADD to add a String in the Items property, I have following error "The constructor on type System.String in not foundable" (this is a translate from french).

Answer (score 0):

The following code solve my issue

```
<Category("GridBox")>
<DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)>
<Editor("System.Windows.Forms.Design.StringCollectionEditor, System.Design", "System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor, System.Drawing")>
Public ReadOnly Property Items() As New List(Of String)
```

**What is very important** is to add `DesignerSerializationVisibility` and `Editor` attributes.

Thanks to jmcilhinney for his help

Comment: Should be `<Editor("System.Windows.Forms.Design.ListControlStringCollectionEditor, System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", GetType(UITypeEditor))>`

Comment: not "should be" but "can also be"

Comment: @Jimi: your solution doesn't compile on my PC using Visual Studio 2022 ! The compiler refuses "GetType" function ! For my test, I have replace it by "System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor, System.Drawing" !

Comment: Of course it does, that's the default Editor for this class. [Third Constructor of the EditorAttribute class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.editorattribute.-ctor). Also note that, in all Constructor, it's clearly specified that the Type must be in the  [Type.AssemblyQualifiedName format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname). Double check what you have inserted

Comment: I have replace GetType(UITYpeEditor) by GetType(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor) and now intellisense (not compile or build) doesn't return BC30002 error (type UITypeEditor is not defined).